# Conditional ranking in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

Suppose you have multiple Pandas data frames that contain game by game data for sports teams' over a season. I happen to have data for all NHL games played in a season, for each team separately. For a team, its data frame looks like this:

```
# An example of a NHL team's data frame (the data are made up):

             Goals for   Goals against    Opponent   O/S   Place  Points  Games played
Date        
2015-12-1            3               2     ANAHEIM    OT    Home      15            12
2015-12-3            1               5     CHICAGO   NaN   Visit      15            13
2015-12-5            3               4    MONTREAL    SO    Home      16            14
2015-12-8            1               0      DALLAS   NaN    Home      18            15
...
```

**What is the most efficient way of determining the daily standings for the teams?** For simplicity, let's just consider league level standings and not the conference / division level standings. I would like to concatenate the standings into a single data frame, which looks something like this:

```
# Concatenated league level standings by date (the data are made up):

Team               BOSTON     BUFFALO    CALGARY    CAROLINA ...
Date        
2015-12-1               1          32         10          15
2015-12-2               3          28          9           9     
2015-12-3               2          26         10           4
2015-12-4               6          27         13           1 
2015-12-5               2          25         15           3 
2015-12-6               5          28         16           2 
...
```

I have actually managed to determine the standings myself, but my implementation is veeeeeeeery slow and dummy. Basically, I'm (1) looping over each game played by a team A (i.e. row in the team's data frame), (2) retrieving the latest game played by another team B (i.e. played before or at the same day as the game being looped over), (3) if the team B should be higher (i.e. better) in the standings than team A based on NHL rules (http://sports.espn.go.com/nhl/news/story?page=nhl/tiebreakers), the current standing for the team A is incremented by one (i.e. I've added a standing column to each team's data frame and the default standing is one). After going through all games played by all teams, I concatenate the standings into one data frame.

I strongly feel there is a much more efficient approach to solving my problem that utilizes the capabilities of Pandas in a much better way. I was forced to go for the looping-thing since I couldn't figure out how to align the rows (i.e. games) from different data frames based on date index. Besides, if I happened to know how to align the rows, I dunno how to sort the columns (i.e. rank the teams) as a whole.

**I suppose the same techniques needed for solving this rather specific question could be applied to many similar situations, such as ranking stocks**. For example, if you wanted to rank the daily returns for stocks based on some conditions (e.g. industry level ranking), I guess it would need a very similar approach to what is needed here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Adapting from @JohnE 's answer, I managed to come up with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Generating some non-random data
rng = [ '2015-10-01', '2015-10-02', '2015-10-03', '2015-10-04',
        '2015-10-01', '2015-10-03', '2015-10-04', '2015-10-06',
        '2015-10-01', '2015-10-04', '2015-10-05', '2015-10-06' ]
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'Team':          [ 'A',    'A', 'A',    'A',    'B', 'B','B',  'B',    'C',    'C', 'C',    'C' ],
                     'Opponent':      [ 'B',    'E', 'F',    'G',    'A', 'H','I',  'C',    'J',    'K', 'L',    'B' ],
                     'Goals for':     [   4,      2,   6,      1,      5,   5,  7,    1,      1,      2,   1,      2 ],
                     'Goals against': [   5,      1,   5,      3,      4,   4,  6,    2,      2,      0,   2,      1 ],
                     'OT/SO':         [ 'o', np.nan, 's', np.nan,    'o', 'o', 's', 's', np.nan, np.nan, 'o',    's' ] },
                     index = pd.to_datetime( rng ) )


# Calculating basic data
df[ 'Points' ] = 0
df.loc[ ( df[ 'Goals for' ] > df[ 'Goals against' ] ), 'Points' ] = 2
df.loc[ ( df[ 'Goals for' ] < df[ 'Goals against' ] ) & ( df[ 'OT/SO' ].isnull() == False ), 'Points' ] = 1
df[ 'Non-SO Win' ] = df[ 'Points' ] == 2
df.loc[ df[ 'OT/SO' ] == 's', 'Non-SO Win' ] = False
df[ 'Goal differential' ] = df[ 'Goals for' ] - df[ 'Goals against' ]


# Determining the standings
results = pd.DataFrame()
for date in set( rng ):
    # aggregating the necessary data
    data = df[ : date ]
    aggr_data = data.groupby('Team').agg( { 'Points': [ 'sum', 'count' ], 
                                            'Non-SO Win': [ 'count' ], 
                                            'Goal differential': [ 'sum' ] } )        

    # Sorting the aggregated df based on (simplified) NHL rules
    aggr_data.sort( [ ( 'Points', 'sum' ), # Points
                      ( 'Points', 'count' ), # Games played
                      ( 'Non-SO Win', 'count' ), # Non-SO wins
                      ( 'Goal differential', 'sum' ) ], # Goal differential
                      ascending = [ False, True, False, False ], 
                      inplace = True )

    # Adding standings = row numbers
    aggr_data[ 'Standing' ] = [ i for i in range( 1, aggr_data.count().values[0] + 1 ) ] 
    results = pd.concat( [ results, aggr_data[ 'Standing' ] ], axis = 'Team' )


results.columns = set( rng )
results = results.T
results.sort_index( inplace = True )
```

My answer is not complete, since the head-to-head points rule is not accounted for... it is the most cumbersome among the rules, IMO. Other than that, I think this approach illustrates how using 'sort' instead of 'rank' is useful when there are multiple criteria for ranking.

Comment: Yeah, I just glanced at the code but it looks pretty good.  It's a good point about rank vs sort.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data below.  I'm going to use 'team' rather than opponent because it seems more natural, but it doesn't matter.  Using either the team or it's opponent (but not both) is all that is needed for basic ranking, although you would need both of them to calculate head-to-head tie-breakers.  But let's start simple.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)

rng = pd.date_range('2015-12-1',periods=4)

df=pd.DataFrame({ 'team':['stlouis']*4+['chicago']*4+['carolina']*4,
                  'goals_for':np.random.randint(0,5,12),
                  'goals_against':np.random.randint(0,5,12) },
                  index=np.tile(rng,3))

df['points'] = np.select( [ df.goals_for  > df.goals_against, 
                            df.goals_for == df.goals_against ], 
                          [ 2, 1] )   # 2 for win, 1 for tie

df = df[['team','goals_for','goals_against','points']]

                team  goals_for  goals_against  points
2015-12-01   stlouis          2              0       2
2015-12-02   stlouis          4              0       2
2015-12-03   stlouis          2              1       2
2015-12-04   stlouis          1              3       0
2015-12-01   chicago          3              4       0
2015-12-02   chicago          2              0       2
2015-12-03   chicago          3              0       2
2015-12-04   chicago          1              4       0
2015-12-01  carolina          1              1       1
2015-12-02  carolina          0              3       0
2015-12-03  carolina          1              2       0
2015-12-04  carolina          1              4       0
```

Now set up a small loop to do this for each date:

```
results=pd.DataFrame()

for r in rng.format():
    points = df[:r].groupby('team')['points'].sum()
    standings = points.rank(ascending=False)
    results = pd.concat( [ results, standings ], axis=1 )

results.columns = rng.format()
```

I don't think anything in there is too complicated.  Here's the intermediate output (for the final date):

```
points

team
carolina    1
chicago     4
stlouis     6

standings

team
carolina    3
chicago     2
stlouis     1
```

And the final table, which is just a concatenation of all the standings for each date (and transposed):

```
results.T

            carolina  chicago  stlouis
2015-12-01         2        3        1
2015-12-02         3        2        1
2015-12-03         3        2        1
2015-12-04         3        2        1
```

Comment: Well, that is what I should be doing, very neat and uncomplicated!

Being precise, you started with a single df containing results for all teams, but I have multiple dfs containing results for individual teams (my 'opponent' column contains the opponents a team has faced each day). Obviously, I just have to concatenate all results into a single df and then your approach should be directly applicable. 

Further, a potential problem is that not all teams are playing at each day. But I guess I just resample the data so that there are no 'missing' dates for teams?

And then the tie-brakers...

Comment: @Pondeh Yeah, you'll need to concatenate.  As far as teams not playing each day, I don't think that should cause any problems so I don't think you need to do anything extra.

Comment: That is correct, resampling is not needed now that I tried. Very good! I gotta still find a way for dealing with tie-brakers.

Comment: @Pondeh  Yeah, I suspect that will take a fairly different approach without much overlap with this problem and will also be more difficult (which are the two reasons I ignored the issue here!).  If you do post a followup question, I would suggest including code for sample data (feel free to take what I did here and change/expand as needed)